# Equivalence of Two Kinds of Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Principle Of Finite Induction (PFI)- If $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a set such that the following conditions are satisfied-

$1.\textrm{ }1\in S,$ and

$2.\textrm{ }k\in S\implies k+1\in S,$

then, $S=\mathbb{N}.$

Principle of Complete Finite Induction (PCFI)- If $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is a set such that the following conditions are satisfied-

$1.\textrm{ }1\in S,$ and

$2.\textrm{ }1,2,\dots,k\in S \implies k+1\in S,$

then, $S=\mathbb{N}.$

Claim- PCFI$\iff$PFI

Proof-

(PCFI$\implies$PFI) Let $S$ be a set such that $1\in S,$ and $k\in S \implies k+1\in S.$ Now, by hypothesis, $1\in S.$ Let $1,2,\dots,m\in S.$ Then, since $m\in S,$ we have that $m+1\in S.$ Hence, $1,2,\dots,m$ being in $S$ implies that $m+1\in S.$ By PCFI, $S=\mathbb{N}.$

(PFI$\implies$PCFI) Let $S$ be a set such that $1\in S,$ and $1,2,\dots,k\in S \implies k+1\in S.$ By hypothesis, $1\in S.$ Let $n\in S.$ From here, how do we show that $n+1\in S?$

My Questions-

I know that if we reformulate PCFI and PFI in terms of propositions, we can say, "Let $P(n)$ be the proposition that $Q(1),Q(2),\dots,Q(n)$ are all true.", and prove PCFI from PFI using this. But, I do not want this approach. This is why I believe that my question is different from other similar questions on this site. How can I proceed? Also, is the first part of my proof correct?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, thanks for pointing it out, but where exactly did I mix up the names? I can't figure out where I mixed them up.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, I'm not sure I follow. In my PFI$\implies$PCFI, I'm trying to use regular, or "weak" induction to show that the set S (satisfying "strong" induction properties) is in fact, $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, I am assuming that weak induction is true. I want to then apply this to a set that satisfies the strong induction properties to show that the set is equal to $\mathbb{N}.$ In my first proof, I assumed that strong induction is true and showed that a set satisfying the weak induction properties is $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, yes. In my second proof, I am assuming weak induction (principle of finite induction). I want to use this to prove strong induction (principle of complete finite induction). That is, I want to use regular induction to show that a set satisfying the properties listed in strong induction is $\mathbb{N}.$ I'm confused, as I don't see any sort of circular reasoning.

Comment: PCFI- If $1\in S$ and $[k]\subseteq S\implies k+1 \in S,$ then $S=\mathbb{N}.$ See what I am assuming. I am only assuming that $1\in S,$ and that $[k]\subseteq S.$ I am *not* assuming that $S=\mathbb{N}.$ This is what I want to prove.

Comment: My question is this- If a set $S$ is such that $1 \in S,$ and $k+1 \in S$ whenever $[k]\subseteq S,$ show that $S=\mathbb{N}$ using weak induction.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, okay if you insist, then I must be missing something. Thank you for your input.

Comment: In my second proof, I want to show that any set $S$ satisfying $1 \in S,$ and $[k]\subseteq S \implies k+1 \in S$ is equal to $\mathbb{N}.$ I want to use weak induction to do so. In the very first line of my second proof, I assumed that $1 \in S,$ and $[k]\subseteq S \implies k+1 \in S.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143063/discussion-between-aqualubix-and-shinrin-yoku).

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, please look at https://youtu.be/UJJeSQJVAtM. In particular, look at 2:01. I did not label my proofs wrong. The proof shown at 2:01 is exactly what I wanted to achieve with my second proof. In their proof, they too, assume a set $S$ satisfying the assumptions of PCFI, just like I did. They then use PFI on a new set $E$ to show that $S=\mathbb{N}.$